# Parse BBCode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, bbcode

I'm trying to do a script who extract tags from a string 

For that, i used RegExp

I simplified my code as much as possible.

```
 var ereg = /(\[text\](.+)\[\/text\])+?/;
 var str = '[text]MyText[/text][text]MyOtherText[/text]';
 result = ereg.exec(str);

 if (result) {
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += "<br>[" + i + "] => " + result[i];
     }
 }
```

Output:

```
 [0] => [text]MyText[/text][text]MyOtherText[/text]
 [1] => [text]MyText[/text][text]MyOtherText[/text]
 [2] => MyText[/text][text]MyOtherText
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RNPQdbwTJ6V7zr_e)

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lemarcque/qn7Lx40u/6/)

My problem is that i want the variable result return me what is between the tags [text][/text], meaning '**MyText**' et '**MyOtherText**'.

Instead it returns me 'MyText ** [/ text] [text] MyOtherText **'.
How do I do this?

My regular expression is not *non-greedy*?

Comment: Make the repetition lazy `(.+?)`.

Comment: If you are not doing this for interest/practise sake then you may want to look at a parser library, I have found this one quite small and useful in the past https://github.com/patorjk/Extendible-BBCode-Parser And of course it depends on the complexity of the BBcode that you need to parse. An example that I gave in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383102/regex-doesnt-stop-matching/28384474#28384474

Comment: @ndn Thank you it is working !

Comment: @Xotic750 Thank you, yes, i'll try to do something with it.

Comment: @Lemarcque,happy to help.